# Private IBOutlets

Tags: private, iboutlet

I just noticed that if one makes a private outlet, that works as well and then one can connect xib objects to that. I wanted to know if there is anyone else who has seen this working as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can make your outlets private.  You can even declare them as instance variables in your `@implementation`, like this:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    __unsafe_unretained IBOutlet UILabel *_myLabel;
}
```

Interface Builder will let you connect that instance variable to an object in your nib.

I usually put my outlets in my `.m` file, either as properties or just as instance variables, unless I have a reason to expose them in the class's public interface.

Comment: Hey thanks ..:) ... Does one really need to use instance variables? I stopped using them some time back and I believe one could do well without using them in case of private IBOutlets too.

Comment: If you need a reference to an object in the nib, you have to put it somewhere.  You can create an instance variable for it explicitly (as in my example), or you can use `@synthesize`, and the compiler will create the instance variable for you.

Comment: Oh yes the 'properties'! Thats what I am doing actually, using private properties for outlets with xibs. Thanks.                                         ps : As you might be able to guess, I am trying to move away from using ivars as a practice.